# Issue with iteratively writing text files with try-except

Tags: python, debugging, exception, io, try-except

The following is my code -

```
for file in files:
    k+=1
    f = str(file)
    with open(f) as data:
        post = json.load(data)
        l+=1
    try:
        query = post["title"]+" - "+cleanText(html.unescape(post["replies"][0]["text"]))
        queries.write(query+'\n')
        i+=1
    except:
        j+=1
        pass
    for i in range(1,len(docs)):
        docs[i] = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]", " ",str(docs[i]))
        document = cleanText(html.unescape(docs[i]))
        documents.write(document+'\n')
queries.close()
documents.close()
```

I have a total of 7000 files. Since I am reading the file just once for parsing the query, I should ideally have 7000 queries, but I see ~ 21k queries being written. Why could this be so? What can be the fix?

The variables k and l have the same value, `k = l = 7000` which is expected.

I am using try-except to bypass `TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable` exception.

Comment: Can you share a [mre]?

Comment: I hope I could, but creating the JSON files is tedious and the actual data is confidential. Sorry about that.

Comment: It doesn't have to be 100% the same, it can all be fake data, just as long as it reproduces the issue. If your issue isn't reproducible to us then it'll be a lot harder for us to debug your code for you. If you want to try debugging yourself, get an IDE that has a debugger, put a breakpoint at the start of your code, and then step through it one by one until you see the issue. In fact we already expect you to have done that at this point ideally.

Comment: The thing is it worked fine for a certain group of files but failed for a separate group. Therefore I can't guarantee a set of fake data to reproduce the issue. The group of files that failed threw `TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable` exception, the other group didn't and therefore I used the try-except to bypass the exception. If this information helps to suggest some fix?

Comment: I suggest stepping through your code line-by-line with a debugger if you haven't already.

Comment: That certainly helped. Thanks a ton. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about the format of your data, but I ran into this issue when using `html.unescape` to parse some JSON files of my own, it turns out for some reason I had empty strings in my JSON, and when ran through the `json` library those empty strings were being converted to the `None` object.

You need to add a check in the code to make sure your object that you're trying to parse isn't None.

Here's how I did it in my code:

```py
            message_body = chat['Text']

            # Convert symbols like '&#39' into the actual character representation
            if (message_body is not None):
                message_body = html.unescape(message_body)
```